# Angular5: Is the good way to make configuration file in binary

Tags: javascript, angular

Is the good way to make configuration file in binary and load serialization to be secure and don't show in web console and then can't be readable. How this can be done. I am using now config.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "apiUrl": "https://api.truesyip.com/",
    "portal": "mesia",
    "tunnel": "monolitu",
    "client": "my-client",
  }
}
```

but this is load file and can be seen in network tab.

Comment: Nothing client-side can be fully hidden and secured. All the code that is executed in a browser is public, and also are all requests that are made to or get back from the server. Developers have to deal with it by managing all security server-side.